# Alarm clock for Mac (OSX) that works reliably, all the time

Tags: osx

My phone is acting up and I don't think I can rely on it to wake me up.

It's important that I wake up on time, and I'm looking for a Mac program that I can rely upon, even when the computer is asleep, unplugged, or with system volume levels uncertain.

I downloaded [**"Wake Up Time - Alarm Clock"**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wake-up-time-alarm-clock/id495945638?mt=12) (the first Google result for "alarm clock Mac"), but the UI and documentation are ambiguous. I couldn't even figure out how to set the alarm within 1 minute, much less have confidence that it would work.

I next downloaded [**"Alarm Clock"**](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20597/alarm-clock), which was recommended in [a 2012 Meta Filter thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/209359/Alarm-clock-computer-help-please-pleeeeeeeeeeease). The app is no longer updated (it seems to have been last modified in 2007), but it reportedly "continues to work with OS X 10.9X." UI is clean (clear prompt to go into preferences if I want it to wake computer from sleep). And easy access to use mp3s avail in iTunes. I'm giving it a try. Fingers crossed.

Anybody have confidence in any other programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Alarm Clock"](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20597/alarm-clock) by [Robbie Hanson](http://www.deusty.com/) has worked flawlessly for me over the past several weeks.

My favorite features:

- Easily select iTunes songs as alarm sound.
- Clear guidance on alarm functionality when computer is asleep.

This simple Mac alarm clock does everything I need.